# Cannot install eth-brownie with pipx

Tags: python, brownie, mac-osx, pipx

I have an MacBook Air M2 with python version 3.11.2
I am getting this error message when I follow the [pipx instructions](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) to install brownie
I tried using pip to install each of these packages individually and I still get the error

```
Fatal error from pip prevented installation. Full pip output in file:
    /Users/katejohnson/.local/pipx/logs/cmd_2023-04-06_17.36.43_pip_errors.log

pip failed to build packages:
    bitarray
    cytoolz
    yarl

Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
    cytoolz/dicttoolz.c:209:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
    yarl/_quoting_c.c:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found

Error installing eth-brownie.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages might not yet have compatible pre-built binaries if you are using  M1 Mac and Python 3.11.2.

Here what you can do, first if you havent install Xcode from the App store then go to a terminal and run `xcode-select --install`

then we install Homebrew and Python 3.9 ( some packages might not yet support Python 3.11.2 )

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install python@3.9
```

then we update our PATH accordingly `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin:$PATH"`

then we restart our shell `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` then

```
python3.9 -m pip install --user pipx
python3.9 -m pipx ensurepath
```

and finaly: `pipx install eth-brownie`

to do that in a virtual env and so keep your version of python do that:

install our env package `python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv`
then we create our virtual env `python3 -m virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.9 myenv` then we activate it ( you have to do it when  you want to use eth-brownie, then we install it inside our virtualenv with `source myenv/bin/activate` then python -m pip install eth-brownie

Comment: Thank you so much for this help! Is it possible to do this without changing my default python version to 3.9? Like can I skip updating PATH? Unfortunately I tried this solution and got the same errors.

Comment: yes in a virtual env you could do that, I update my answer

Comment: I got it working now thank you!!!